# Xcode will not start from the Applications folder

Tags: c++, xcode

I am currently on a Mac, and I tried copying the Xcode icon to the applications folder and now Xcode doesn't work. I get the following error when trying to open Xcode: Xcode cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of Mac OSX.... 
I tried dragging back Xcode back to the Developer folder by navigating to Macintosh HD and then Developer, but Xcode still doesn't work. Is there a specific folder in Developer that it should be in?

Comment: In general, XCode needs to be installed in **Developer->Applications** folder and this is the installation place by default. Which version of XCode are you trying to install ?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. thanks

Comment: @kachilous - +1 for figuring out your self.

Comment: @kachilous - Care to share your solution?

Comment: @McMinton -- I dragged Xcode from the folder that it wasn't supposed to be in to Developer -> Applications, which is the folder it should be in and it worked.

Comment: @kachilous: You can answer your own question. I edited the title to help people find this in the future. If you put the answer in answer form it'll make it a better question and answer entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dragged Xcode from the folder that it wasn't supposed to be in to Developer -> Applications, which is the folder it should be in and it worked